# Question in understanding terminology in Galois Theory from Hungerford Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology, galois-theory

While self studying algebra from Thomas Hungerford I have following question in understanding terminology on page 253 of textbook.

Consider this line of textbook

> Let n be a positive integer, K an arbitrary field, E the subfield of symmetric rational functions in $ K(x_{1},..., x_{n} ) $ and $f_1, f_2,..., f_n \in E $ the elementary symmetric functions in $x_1 , x_2,..., x_n$ over K.

What does author mean by $f_1, f_2,..., f_n \in E $?

Does it mean that range of $f_{i}$'s belongs to E?

Clearly, it is a function in variables $x_{1} ,..., x_{n} $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the $f_i$'s them-self belong to $E$, not their range. The set $E$ contains all symmetric rational functions and hence the $n$ [elementary symmetric functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial#Definition) $f_1, f_2, \dots, f_n$ are elements of $E$.

*(Note that the elementary symmetric functions are called $e_i$ instead of $f_i$ in the Wikipedia article I linked.)*

Comment: what does " over K " means in " Consider this line of textbook" in question asked?

Comment: It means that the coefficients in the symmetric polynomials are elements of $K$.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that
\begin{align*}
f_1(x_1,\dots,x_n)&=\sum_{i}x_i,\\
f_2(x_1,\dots,x_n)&=\sum_{i<j}x_ix_j,\\
&\ \ \vdots\\
f_n(x_1,\dots,x_n)&=x_1\cdots x_n.
\end{align*}
You can check that each of this function $f_i$ is symmetric, that is
$$
f_i(x_{\sigma(1)},\dots,x_{\sigma(n)})=f_i(x_1,\dots,x_n)
$$
for all $\sigma \in S_n$ and all $i=1,\dots,n$. So $f_1,\dots,f_n\in E$.